# Robotframework How to uploadfile to the website with RIDE

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

This is my code

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Login}          xpath=/html/body/app/main/login/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/button

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    OPEN
    LOGIN
    Sleep    5s
    ADD TOPIC
    Sleep    2s
    SelectType
    TypePDF
    Sleep    5s
    AddFile

*** Keywords ***
OPEN
    Open Browser    https://********** \ \ \    googlechrome

LOGIN

Input Text    id=inputEmail3    ********

Input Text    id=inputPassword3  *******

 Click Element    xpath=/html/body/app/main/login/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/button

ADD TOPIC
    Click Element    xpath=/html/body/app/main/pages/div/div/news/div/news-list/button

SelectType
    Click Element    id=selectType

TypePDF
    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="selectType"]/option[5]

AddFile
    Click Button    xpath=/html/body/app/main/pages/div/div/news/div/news-add/ba-card/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ba-file-uploader/div/span/button
    Sleep    2s
    Choose File    <input type="file" id="myFile">    C:{/}User${/}pr.com${/}Download${/}base.png

Addpicture

Choose File    //input[@type='file']    C:\Users\pr.com\Downloads\b.jpg
```

This is the result

```
Test
| FAIL |
File 'C:{/}User\pr.com\Download\base.png' does not exist on the local file system
```

I use:

```
Python version 2.7.14
Robotframework ride  1.5.2.1
```

Comment: Paste your code and output in question, you can use '{}' option to format code..

Comment: no images. paste the code in the question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Thank you for the warning bro

Comment: see my updated new reply

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanator. It is literally looking for a file named `C:{/}...`. Do you really have a folder named `{/}`?

Comment: no. I don't have it

Answer (score 1):

From the document

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html

Because Robot Framework uses the backslash ('\') as an escape character in the test data, using a literal backslash requires duplicating it like in r'c:\path\file.txt. '

So use "\" double slash when u r providing path to file

if it still does not work , then check if the path you provide exists or not

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Open Browser and login
*** Keywords ***
Open Browser and login
    File Should Exist    C:\\Users\\pr.com\\Downloads\\b.jpg
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting for "File Should Exist" KW..ignore previous post

Comment: "File 'C:\Users\pr.com\Desktop\DtacPDF\Userspr.comDownloadsone.pdf' does not exist."

Comment: This is the result

Comment: you can see yourself, what path i have given and what path you are getting ? are you sure you run the same script or u made any changes in yours!!

Comment: It's pass !!    Thank you very much

Comment: you can upvote and accept ( right tick) below downvote button my answer if its helpful to you

Comment: I have a new problem.   i want to uploadfile.pdf  but  this is the result  => Test                                                                                               | FAIL |
There were no alerts

Comment: Ask a new question, your previous question is already resolve

Answer (score 0):

For chrome below code should work

```
Choose File    //input[@type='file']    C:/Users/pr.com/Downloads/b.jpg
```

Let me know if you still get issue

Comment: Why "for chrome"? Shouldn't this work for any browser?

Comment: Hey Bryan, long back I have seen some issue in Firefox. At present it works for both chrome and firefox

Comment: because i think chrome is stably   maybe

Comment: Hi  Karthikeya  this code is work but  I found a new problem.

Comment: I would like to add a file pdf , but my ketyword is doesn't work  

this   is   the result ==>  Test                                                                                               | FAIL |
There were no alerts

Comment: as per you code, you didn't give the path for pdf file anywhere